# Comparing Java Strings with the `compareTo()` method

Tags: java, regex, string, compare

As a generalisation of string comparisons made by the `compareTo()` method:

**For two given letters:**

- Two letters with matching values, the resulting value will be 0.
- If a given letter comes in place before another given letter, the value of the comparison of the two be negative.
- If a given letter's place comes after another's, the value of the comparison of the two be positive.

This may be considered as such:

> In the order of 26 English-language letters, "A" may be considered as index 1, and "B" to be index 2:
>
> Therefore, A = 1; B = 2.
>
> A - B = -1.

*To reach the value A, B must be reduced by 1, or B - 1 = 1 = A.*

*For example:*

```
  int result;
  
  String letterA = "a";
  String letterB = "b";
  
  result = letterA.compareTo(letterB);
  System.out.println("The difference between the letter \"a\" and the letter \"b\" will be equivalent to: " + result);
```

**When considering a string of characters:**

The difference of the alphabetical index of the first two characters whose string-character indices along their respective strings are equivalent and whose alphabetical indices do not match will be the value returned by the `String.compareTo(String)` method (where "String" represents a generalised string value).

*For example:*

```
  int result;
  
  String stringBA = "ba";
  String stringBD = "bd";
  
  result = stringBA.compareTo(stringBD);
  System.out.println("The difference between string \"ba\" and string \"bd\" will be equivalent to: " + result);
```

The comparison will evaluate to -3, as the difference between the letters ultimately compared within the method are the characters "a" and "d", where their alphabetical indices are 1 and 4, respectively.

This may be said as: *To reach the value of A, D must be reduced by 3, or D - 3 = A.*

> Could this be considered accurate?

Comment: Might anyone know how to submit a wiki post? I was unable to post this when I attempted. I feel like this could really help newer users understand the `compareTo(String)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could this be considered accurate?

It depends on what you mean by accurate.

- As a specification, it is incomplete:

  - It only deals with characters that are "letters" and strings containing "letters".  By contrast, `String.compareTo` works for any sequence(s) of codepoints.
  - It does not deal with Strings of unequal length which have the same character subsequences for their common part.
- Ignoring the holes in the spec, it is an over-specification.  The javadoc for `String.compareTo` does not specify precisely what the returned value is.  It just says whether it is zero, negative or positive.
- Ignoring the holes, it looks like it is an adequate model for the behaviour of (at least) the implementation of `compareTo` that @user3580294 has found.

The real specification for String.compareTo is given by the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).  It is unambiguous, and definitive.  There is no need to restate it in other words ... IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source for `String#compareTo()`:

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
    int len1 = value.length;
    int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;

    int k = 0;
    while (k < lim) {
        char c1 = v1[k];
        char c2 = v2[k];
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 - c2;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

Based on this, I believe you are correct. Either the difference between the first pair of nonmatching characters at a given index is returned or the difference in lengths is returned.

Comment: Great. I was fairly certain. I wanted to post this as a wiki-post, because I felt it could help a lot of newer programmers understand the `compareTo(String)` method. I know, personally, it was a point of confusion (due to lack of clear explanation) for me.

However, I don't know how to post wiki/self-answer posts.

Comment: @alx there's a community wiki checkbox at the bottom of the post, before the preview. You can only mark as community wiki your own question/answers.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ah, didn't notice that before. Not sure if I should mark this as wiki based on StephenC's answer, but I'll keep that in mind for future use. Thanks!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah, but it said my answer didn't meet community standards?

Comment: Hi, could someone plz explain this line of code: int len2 = anotherString.value.length;